# Open Airplay popover in my custom button

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, airplay

I'm wondering is it possible to create a custom airplay button and add it to a toolbar? i.e. I would like to create button that open the same popover that original AirPlay button, to share all the screen.
I saw that it is possible to do with MPMoviePlayerController or WebView, but in that way I send on air a video or audio, but non all the screen...

Thans

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5 there were some [hoops to jump through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174204/customize-the-airplay-buttons-appearance). In iOS 6, it's much easier. Add a [`MPVolumeView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and use `setRouteButtonImage:forState:` to change the icon:

```
airplayView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:airplayContainer.bounds];
airplayView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
[airplayView setRouteButtonImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"airplay"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[airplayView setRouteButtonImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"airplay-highlighted"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[airplayView setRouteButtonImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"airplay-selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[airplayContainer addSubview:airplayView]; // or add it to your toolbar or wherever
```

`airplayContainer` is just a plain `UIView` I added in Interface Builder to get the layout I wanted.